# Cannot cast object 'parseDate' with class 'java.lang.String' to class 'java.util.Date' in grails

Tags: json, grails

I am new to grails and want to learn, Here in this code I am creating jsonDate and using in create method. when I am sending data from SoapUi, I am getting error like `Cannot cast object '13/01/2014' with class 'java.lang.String' to class 'java.util.Date'`.

```
class RequestMainController {
    static scaffold = true
    static allowedMethods = [save: "POST", updat``e: "PUT", delete: "DELETE"]
    def index(Integer max) {
        params.max = Math.min(max ?: 10, 100)
        respond RequestMain.list(params), model:[requestMainInstanceCount: RequestMain.count()]
    }

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    //System.out.println(Current Date  + sdf.format(new Date());
    String mydate = "01-08-2011";
    Date parseDate = sdf.parse(mydate);

    def slurper = new JsonSlurper()
    def requestMain = slurper.parseText('{"milestoneSequenceNumber":"111","recordStartDate":"13/01/2014",
                                          "recordEndDate":"13/01/2014","application":"app","applicationType":"A""}');

    def create(){
        //def jsonObject = grails.converters.JSON.parse(requestMain) 
        def milestoneSequenceNumber = requestMain.milestoneSequenceNumber
        def recStartDate = requestMain.recordStartDate
        def recEndDate = requestMain.recordEndDate
        def application = requestMain.application
        def applicationType = requestMain.applicationType
        System.out.println(" MILESTONE_SEQ_NO = $milestoneSequenceNumber,REC_START_DATE = $recStartDate, REC_START_DATE=$recEndDate,APPLICATION=$application,APPL_TYPE=$applicationType)

        render(view:"create", action:"save")
    }

    def save() {
        RequestMain requestMain1 = new RequestMain()

        requestMain1.mimeNo = requestMain.milestoneSequenceNumber
        requestMain1.recStartDate = requestMain.recordStartDate
        requestMain1.recEndDate = requestMain.recordEndDate
        requestMain1.application = requestMain.application
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        String mydate = "01-08-2011";
        Date parseDate = sdf.parse(mydate);
        requestMain1.save()
        render "Success!"
    }
}
```

Comment: Which line from the above code actually throws the exception?

Answer (score 4):

actually the error you are getting inside save on line-

```
 Date parseDate = sdf.parse(mydate);
```

is because you cannot change date string directly into SimpleDateFormat. So you will need to change it to Date class object.

```
String mydate = "01-08-2011";
def parsedDate = Date.parse("yyyy-MM-dd", mydate);
Date parseDate = sdf.parse(parsedDate);
```

While doing so will also be illogical because parsedDate will already be an object of class Date so you need not convert it again.

If you are not using SimpleDateFormat for any specific reason you can always use the following methods-

1. Change Date to String of a particular format-

   ```
   def myStringDate = dateObj.format("yyyy-MM-dd");
   ```
2. Change String to Date

   ```
   def myDate = Date.parse("yyyy-MM-dd", myStringDate);
   ```

These methods are more GROOVYish and will make your work easy.

These passed date formats can be made using the formats specified in java documentation- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you receive this error after trying to save from create view it seems that you forget to convert strings to `java.lang.Date` in `save()` method. Before assigning to `requestMain1` properties convert them to `java.lang.Date`:

```
def save() {
    RequestMain requestMain1 = new RequestMain()

    requestMain1.mimeNo = requestMain.milestoneSequenceNumber
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    requestMain1.recStartDate = dateFormat.parse(requestMain.recordStartDate)
    requestMain1.recEndDate = dateFormat.parse(requestMain.recordEndDate)
    (...etc...)
}
```